# How to generate identical random values for float32 and float64 in PyTorch?

Tags: python, initialization, precision, torch, random-seed

I'm trying to see how the choice between float32 and float64 affects the convergence of my model, but I want the initial parameters of the model and the randomly generated dataset to be the same in both cases. Therefore, I did the following at the start of my script:

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
```

However, if I generate random values with different dtypes the results differ:

```
import torch

torch.set_printoptions(precision=15)

# float32
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float32)
torch.manual_seed(0) 
print(torch.rand(1)) # 0.496256589889526

# float64
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float64)
torch.manual_seed(0)
print(torch.rand(1)) # 0.970053001806553
```

Which makes sense, because a float64 number cannot be fully represented by a float32 number. Nevertheless, is there a method that makes the random values somewhat identical? Of course I could so something like

```
torch.rand(1,dtype=torch.float32).type(torch.float64)
```

But doing this everywhere in my code is a pain.